# Referencing a executable (game-)server

Tags: .net, project-structure

I am currently working on a little MonoGame project. While planning this, i came to a problem: I want to separate the game logic to an other assembly. The client and the server need this logic assembly, the client can also start a server.

My question is now: should i separate the server in an specific assembly, or should i reference the server executable in my client project?

Here is a diagram, to visual my question:

[image]

If you want to see the source code, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/Flosus/Mini).

**Edit**:
To make it clear:I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835635/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-reference-an-exe-file-in-c-sharp-project) question on stackoverflow and thought, an executable server, shipped with the client could make a separate assembly for the common code obsolete.

**Edit2**:
As Robert Harvey wrote in the chat, i should still separate them. I will do this and add an answer, once available for me...

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @gnat I don't know if the source code would helps you, because it doesn't have any 'server logic', but i made a diagram : )

Comment: Only create a common assembly if you actually have code that you want to share between the two assemblies for DRY purposes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I Have common code. That is not the problem here.  A good advise, but i have to share IDs and such.

Comment: It really depends on what your goals are.  People write View Model objects all the time to achieve decoupling, but in practice these objects can live in any assembly that is convenient.  In other words, the organization rules for assemblies does not necessarily correspond to the organization rules for types or IDs.  The most common organizing principle is that you put related types in the same assembly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I plan to give strong rights to the client, which are also on the server side. (I want to allow the player have programmable minions, which means they  share at least a the AI logic.)

Comment: None of that has anything to do with assembly organization, unless you plan on having the client assembly in some other physical location and talking to the server over the Internet or LAN.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26870/discussion-between-alex-h-and-robert-harvey).